# What API returns HTML5-friendly video links?

Tags: html, video

I would like to experiment with embedding videos in HTML5 - and to check some applications with different content.

Where can I find a good collection of online videos with corresponding metadata?  A collection with a decent query/search/filter API would be great!

**Update**: To test an app, I would need at least 50 movies playable vie a `<video>` tag, with supplied title, atrist and tags.  A downloadable library of short movies with an index file is good enough as well.

Comment: something like Sintel [http://www.sintel.org/download] or Big Buck Bunny will give you some good source content to work from. Not sure what you mean by corresponding metadata

Comment: I am looking for a collection (tens/hundreds) of video files.  Metadata will be title, author, year, etc.

Comment: why do the videos themselves have to be different?

Comment: I just checked YouTube.  You can set it up to use an [HTML5 video viewer](http://www.youtube.com/html5), but I don't see any video tags in the source...

Comment: Which browsers `<video>` tag? Different browsers support different video formats, unfortunately (although Firefox is now adding support for h.264). see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support

Comment: Chrome is a good start

Comment: I don't see the value of testing different videos from the same source. They will all be encoded identically so if one works they will all. You should test videos from different sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the TEDTalks RSSs?

- Standard video feed of TEDTalks to use as a podcast. http://feeds.feedburner.com/TEDTalks_video
- RSS feed in high resolution. http://feeds.feedburner.com/TedtalksHD

I think the RSS should be enough but If you need more than that you can also try their API: http://developer.ted.com/API_Docs

Comment: Great! Once I knew that! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

DailyMotion has an API: http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/graph-api.html
Vimeo has APIs: http://developer.vimeo.com/apis
both of them might take some fiddling to get the actual video (eg for Vimeo http://player.vimeo.com/external/.sd.mp4?s=) but if the metadata collection is important both of these will help and you can just play the Sintel video

Comment: Those APIs do not support direct linking to the video file, only embedding (i.e., link to an iframe.).  I am quite sure the TOS would disallow "fiddling" with the url.

Comment: if it's for a PoC I'm sure they won't be too stressed, and your question was specifically for a testing scenario because you didn't want to create your own source. Best of luck finding it